# Splitting comma separated values for an HTML table

Tags: html, vb.net, html-table

I have a 2 column table separated by commas, as per the below:

```
|----------------|---------------------| 
|  description   |        price        |
|----------------|---------------------|            
|    A,B,C,D     |    £1,£4,£7,£1.50   | 
|----------------|---------------------|           
|    D,F,A,G     |     £4,£8,£9,£10    | 
|----------------|---------------------|
```

I am trying to build an html string to add the above comma separated values into a HTML table. So it looks like the below:

```
|----------------|---------------------| 
|  description   |        price        |
|-----------   --|---------------------|            
|        A       |          £1         | 
|----------------|---------------------|           
|        B       |          £4         | 
|----------------|---------------------|   
|        C       |          £7         | 
|----------------|---------------------|   
|        D       |       £1.50         | 
|----------------|---------------------|   
|        D       |          £4         | 
|----------------|---------------------|   
|        A       |          £8         | 
|----------------|---------------------|   
|        F       |          £9         | 
|----------------|---------------------|   
|        G       |         £10         | 
|----------------|---------------------|
```

I currently have the below code, which works for the description field, but I am not sure how to get the values for the price.

Do I need to have a separate FOR loop for each column?

```
For Each Product As String In Form1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString.Split(", ")
    Products.AppendLine(String.Format("     <tr>{0}
                                            <td>{1}</td>{0}
                                            </tr>", Environment.NewLine,
                                            Product))

Next Product
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim Products As New System.Text.StringBuilder

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    Dim colA As String() = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString.Split(","c)
    Dim colB As String() = row.Cells(3).Value.ToString.Split(","c)

    For i As Integer = 0 To Math.Max(colA.Length, colB.Length) - 1
        Products.AppendLine("<tr>")
        Products.AppendLine(String.Format("<td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td>",
                                            If(i > colA.Length - 1, "", colA(i)),
                                            If(i > colB.Length - 1, "", colB(i))
                                         )
                           )
        Products.AppendLine("</tr>")
    Next
Next
```

This will still work if the number of descriptions and prices on the same row are different.

Comment: Thanks that's closer, its showing the correct price, but it gives lot of duplicate rows. I need one unique row per product in the ColA array

Comment: @user3580480 OK, but in your example output are duplicates. Please create a new question for this or edit this question and show the desired output.

Comment: There are no duplicates in my example output. The first table has a description field with 8 product values in it, the output table has 8 products?

Comment: @user3580480 It's not obvious from the question that there are multiple rows per product in your datagridview. If you test with the data you provided in your question you get the desired output. I assumed you meant the duplicate descriptions.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, your answer has got be closer to what I am trying to achieve

Comment: I just remove the outer loop and hey presto! Thanks @MatSnow I have marked as answered